# "This browser or app may not be secure" error when using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate gmail by downloading attachments from my inbox using selenium. But, it is showing me this error "This browser or app may not be secure". I looked around and found that OAuth will solve the problem. But, I don't know how to use it or if it is the right tool to use. Can anyone help me solve this error. Is Oauth the right tool? Will using any other browser solve the problem?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.binary_location = "/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome"    
options.add_argument("--start-maximized") 
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox") #bypass OS security model
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage") 

options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches["enableautomation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, 
executable_path=r'./chromedriver')
driver.get('http://gmail.com/')
```

Error:
This browser or app may not be secure. Learn more
Try using a different browser. If you’re already using a supported browser, you can refresh your screen and try again to sign in.

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: I am using Chrome

Comment: Update your question with your code so we can pinpoint what went wrong

Comment: Also post the full error traceback

Comment: The IDE does not show any errors. But, the chrome browser does.

Comment: Sorry the error is not "This browser is not supported", it is "This browser or app may not be secure"

Answer (score 0):

Was having the same issue and i found [this](https://gist.github.com/ikegami-yukino/51b247080976cb41fe93) thread in GitHub.

The solution that worked for me was to use this driver: `undetected_chromedriver` instead of the normal `ChromeDriver`.

```
    import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc

    chrome_options = uc.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-plugins-discovery")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
    chrome_options.add_argument("user_agent=DN")

    self.browser = uc.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    self.browser.delete_all_cookies()

    # example of loggin in to youtube without getting that issue
    self.browser.get('http://youtube.com')

    login_button_init = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@aria-label='Sign in']") 
    login_button_init.click()

    # locate the login button
    login_button = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//paper-button[@aria-label='Sign in']")
    login_button.click()

    # get email and set to email input box
    email = self.browser.find_element_by_id("identifierId")
    myemail = os.environ.get('YOUTUBE_EMAIL')
    email.send_keys(myemail)

    # click next button
    email_next_button = self.browser.find_element_by_id("identifierNext")
    email_next_button.click()

    # get password and set to password input box
    password = self.browser.find_element_by_name("password")
    mypassword = os.environ.get('YOUTUBE_PASSWORD')
    password.send_keys(mypassword)
    sleep(2)

    # click next button to log in
    pass_next_button = self.browser.find_element_by_id("passwordNext")
    pass_next_button.click()
```

Comment: this code works but .v2 shouldn't be included in the import, maybe it used to work but it doesn't anymore. just import using 'import undetected_chromedriver as uc'